# Something wrong with PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a forum-like section for my website. It's not posting, and I don't know why. Here's my PHP *and* html

```php
    <?php
if ($_POST) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $content = $_POST['commentContent'];
    $handle = fopen("comments.html", "a");
    fwrite($handle, "<h2 class='Roboto-Slab'>$title</h2>", "<br>", "<h3 
    class='Roboto-Slab'>By $name</h3>", "<p class='Roboto-Slab'>$content</p>");
    fclose($handle);


    }

?>
```

```html
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <textarea class="comment-boxmain" rows="20" cols="40" name="commentContent" 
    placeholder="Start Typing...."></textarea><br>
    <input class="comment-boxname" placeholder="Title" type="text" 
    name="title">
    <input class="comment-boxname" placeholder="Your Name" type="text" 
    name="name">
    <input class="comment-btn" type="submit" value="post"><br>
    </form>
    <?php include "comments.html"; ?>
```

Please check out the answer at cvmblog.com/forum.php if that will help.

Comment: Well, what happens? Side note, this code is *highly* insecure. I can drop any sort of nasty HTML into your `comments.html` with this, like redirects to a malicious site.

Comment: you can add your .php in action attribute of the form

Comment: fwrite($handle, "<h2 class='Roboto-Slab'>$title</h2><br><h3 
    class='Roboto-Slab'>By $name</h3><p class='Roboto-Slab'>$content</p>");

Comment: I apologize.. it does nothing

Comment: Jeric, could you give me a snippet of the code or something? I'm not sure I'm following...

Comment: You will have many more serious problems to resolve then this if you will use this code.

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation is done with dots (.), and not commas (,).

Replace:

```
fwrite($handle, "<h2 class='Roboto-Slab'>$title</h2>", "<br>", "<h3 
class='Roboto-Slab'>By $name</h3>", "<p class='Roboto-Slab'>$content</p>");
```

With:

```
fwrite($handle, "<h2 class='Roboto-Slab'>$title</h2>". "<br>". "<h3 
class='Roboto-Slab'>By $name</h3>". "<p class='Roboto-Slab'>$content</p>");
```

And it will work. However, this concatenation is useless. You can do simply:

```
fwrite($handle, "<h2 class='Roboto-Slab'>$title</h2><br><h3 class='Roboto-Slab'>By $name</h3><p class='Roboto-Slab'>$content</p>");
```

Also check if comments.html file has CHMOD 777. Furthermore, enable error_reporting on your php.ini file, as the PHP error thrown on this case could guide you to the error line easily.

---

Here's an implementation of your code secured against stored XSS (the vulnerability that allows people to insert HTML and Javascript code on your page) as well as RCE (remote code execution):

```html
 <?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    $title = strip_tags($_POST['title']);
    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $content = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($_POST['commentContent']));
    $handle = fopen("comments.html", "a");
    fwrite($handle, "<h2 class='Roboto-Slab'>$title</h2><br><h3 
    class='Roboto-Slab'>By $name</h3><p class='Roboto-Slab'>$content</p>");
    fclose($handle);


    }

?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <textarea class="comment-boxmain" rows="20" cols="40" name="commentContent" 
    placeholder="Start Typing...."></textarea><br>
    <input class="comment-boxname" placeholder="Title" type="text" 
    name="title">
    <input class="comment-boxname" placeholder="Your Name" type="text" 
    name="name">
    <input class="comment-btn" type="submit" value="post"><br>
    </form>
    <?php echo file_get_contents("comments.html"); ?>
```

Also, do some searching about database engines (if you want to still using files, take a look on implementation of flat-files databases, as it's called).

Comment: Thankyou people. I got it to work, but could I please get some instructions on how I can make it safer?

Comment: Hi, @WillHoffman! I suggest you to take a look on [Damn Vulnerable Web App](http://www.dvwa.co.uk/). It simulates a site full of vulnerabilities and the respective materials about them. There you will learn how attacks like RCE (remote command/code execution), XSS, SQL Injection works, as well as ways to defending against them and creating secure applications, taking care about the user inputs (forms and uploads, mainly). [This](https://www.exploit-db.com/docs/39434.pdf) is also very cool.

Comment: Somehow I feel guilty for sharing hacking material with a 10yo young developer. Unfortunately it's needed to be able to hack in order not to be hacked. I only hope you can do a good use of the knowledge you get here.